# How to divide fabric.js canvas into 4 equal parts?

Tags: canvas, fabricjs

I need to know how to divide the canvas into four equal parts. As well as to know for adding objects separately into each parts.

I tried it by creating 2 canvases into single canvas,but it did not working.

Answer (score 0):

For that you can check  [fabric clipPaths example](http://fabricjs.com/clippath-part4)

> ```
> (function() {
>   var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('ex10');
>   var clipPath = new fabric.Rect({ width: 250, height:250, top: 0, left: 0, absolutePositioned: true });
>   var clipPath2 = new fabric.Rect({ width: 250, height:250, top: 0, left: 250, absolutePositioned: true });
>   var clipPath3 = new fabric.Rect({ width: 250, height:250, top: 250, left: 0, absolutePositioned: true });
> var clipPath4 = new fabric.Rect({ width: 250, height:250, top: 250, left: 250, absolutePositioned: true });
>   fabric.Image.fromURL('assets/dragon.jpg', function(img) {
>     img.clipPath = clipPath;
>     img.scaleToWidth(250);
>     canvas.add(img);
>   });
>   fabric.Image.fromURL('assets/dragon2.jpg', function(img) {
>     img.clipPath = clipPath2;
>     img.scaleToWidth(250);
>     img.left= 250;
>     canvas.add(img);
>   });
>     fabric.Image.fromURL('assets/dragon2.jpg', function(img) {
>     img.clipPath = clipPath3;
>     img.scaleToWidth(250);
>     img.top= 250;
>     canvas.add(img);
>   });
>   fabric.Image.fromURL('assets/dragon.jpg', function(img) {
>     img.clipPath = clipPath4;
>     img.scaleToWidth(250);
>       img.top= 250;
>       img.left= 250;
>     canvas.add(img);
>   });
> })()
> ```